# How to fix NestedScrollView still scrollable when there's in-sufficient amount of content

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to achieve something similiar to the drawing below :

[image: My Design]

So there will be some other content (top part of the screen) and there will be a tabBar View inside. When I first load the screen I want to still show the `other content` and when it scroll Down I want the `other content` to be able to be hidden and the `TabBar view` will be at the top (sliverPersistentHeader). I manage to achieve this using NestedScrollView and TabBarview

but The problem is with my content of each Tab. Since I want my content of each tabBar to be scrollable so I put singleChildsScrollView inside of my tabBar. But when there's only little bit of content(since it's dynamic - there might be a lot of content and might be a litle bit) it's still scrollable and resulting bad UI (like the content is cropped).

How to fix this ?

Here's my code:

```
NestedScrollView(
          controller: MainDetailCollabTicketPage.detailCollabScrollController,
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, isScrolled) {
            return [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: ReusableTicketHeaderContent(
                    ticketData: ticketData,
                    source: 'detail_ticket_page',
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              /// Filter Bar
              SliverPersistentHeader(
                pinned: true,
                floating: true,
                delegate: TabBarHeaderDelegate(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                  tabBar: TabBar(
                    controller: collabTabController,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: 'main'.tr()),
                      Tab(text: 'solver'.tr()),
                    ],
                  ),
                  tabBarController: collabTabController!,
                  ticketData: ticketData,
                  selectedTabIndex: selectedTabIndex,
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(controller: collabTabController, children: [
            /// Container for work related with client
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0, vertical: 10.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ReusablePositionWidget(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          ReusableRoleWidget(
                            ticketId: ticketId,
                            ticketData: ticketData,
                            solversStatus: solversStatus,
                            roleBuilt: 'client',
                            povStatus: povStatus,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

            /// Container for work related with solver
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  if (ticketData['temp_solver_id'].length < 1 &&
                      ticketData['solver_id'].length < 1)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            'assets/logo/solver.png',
                            height: 100,
                            width: 120,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 10),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'tooltipSolverHeader',
                                  style: primaryColor500Style.copyWith(
                                      fontSize: fontSize16),
                                ).tr(),
                                const SizedBox(height: 4),
                                Text(
                                  'tooltipSolverDesc',
                                  style: primaryColor400Style.copyWith(
                                      fontSize: fontSize12),
                                ).tr(),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
```

Comment: you want exactly like this

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code:**

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    class DemoTabBAr extends StatefulWidget {
      const DemoTabBAr({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<DemoTabBAr> createState() => _DemoTabBArState();
    }
    
    class _DemoTabBArState extends State<DemoTabBAr>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      late TabController _controller;
      int _selectedIndex = 0;
    
      List<Widget> list = [
        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.card_travel)),
        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart)),
      ];
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        // Create TabController for getting the index of current tab
        _controller = TabController(length: list.length, vsync: this);
    
        _controller.addListener(() {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = _controller.index;
          });
          print("Selected Index: " + _controller.index.toString());
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              toolbarHeight: 200,
              bottom: TabBar(
                onTap: (index) {
                  // Should not used it as it only called when tab options are clicked,
                  // not when user swapped
                },
                controller: _controller,
                tabs: list,
              ),
              
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
              controller: _controller,
              children: [
                Center(
                    child: Text(
                      _selectedIndex.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                    )),
                Center(
                    child: Text(
                      _selectedIndex.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]